# mac os x - sem_open retuns errno 0, Undefined error

Tags: macos, semaphore

I want to create a semaphore in mac os x:

```
const char *semaphore_open_path = "/tmp/sem_handle_open";
errno = 0;
sem_t *semaphore_handle_open = sem_open(semaphore_open_path, O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR, 0);
if(semaphore_handle_open == SEM_FAILED || !semaphore_handle_open)
{
    printf("ERROR sem_open init: %s , %d\n", strerror(errno), errno);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

I get error : `ERROR sem_open init: Undefined error: 0 , 0`

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: I do set errno = 0 before calling sem_open, so that could be a reason why I get Undefined error: 0, BUT why does it enter in the if statement if the call succeeded?

Comment: I've solved it like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28167419/mac-os-x-sem-open-fail

Answer (score 2):

`sem_open` expects a name, not a path. Also, `errno` should be declared as `extern int errno`, it will always be zero otherwise!

This snippet works fine on my Mac.

```
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

extern int errno;

int main(void) {

  sem_t *sem = sem_open("semaphore", O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR, 0);
  if (!sem) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s (%d)", strerror(errno), errno);
  }
  return 0;

}
```

Comment: I changed the path to a simple name, but still I get the same error.

Comment: About declaring extern int errno; I'm not sure. The documentation (I know its linux and my question is regarding mac os) says this: "It was common in traditional C to declare errno manually (i.e.,
       extern int errno) instead of including <errno.h>.  Do not do this.
       It will not work with modern versions of the C library.  However, on
       (very) old UNIX systems, there may be no <errno.h> and the
       declaration is needed." http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html